# Problemas al mostrar un componente react con un ternario

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo el siguiente código en react

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import Tarea from "./Tarea";

const ListadoTareas = () => {
    const tareasProyecto = { nombre: "Elegir Plataforma", estado: true };

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <h2>Proyecto: </h2>

            <ul className="listado-tareas">
                {tareasProyecto.length === 0 ? (
                    <li className="tarea">
                        <p>No hay Tareas</p>
                    </li>
                ) : tareasProyecto.map(tarea => (<Tarea tarea ={tarea} />))}
            </ul>
        </Fragment>
    );
};

export default ListadoTareas;
```

El detalle es que en la consola no me da error pero en el navegador me aparece una pantalla en roja con el siguiente error `TypeError: tareasProyecto.map is not a function`

Comment: Si dice eso es por qué no es un elemento iterable

Comment: Juan, como ha dicho el usuario `BetaM` map solo funciona con iterables, tareas proyecto es un `objeto` y un objeto no es iterable por `map`, puesto que el metodo `map` es originario de los arrays, sin embargo no es estrictamente necesario que cambies toda tu estructura solo por eso. te voy a dar una clave, deberias usar el metodo `entries` de tu objeto llamado `tareasProyecto` e iterar por medio de `tareasProyecto.entries()` en vez de `tareasProyecto`.

Comment: O en caso de que solo necesites los valores y no las llaves entonces usarias `Object.values()`, en ese caso seria `tareasProyecto.values()`.

Comment: Además del problema del iterable que mencionan los colegas, el operador condicional debería usarse para expresar solo una línea de código.

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente Tareas proyecto como lo tenes declarado es un objeto key value.
`const tareasProyecto = { nombre: "Elegir Plataforma", estado: true };`
y cuando intentas hacer:

```javascript
tareasProyecto.length
// devuelve undefined
```

Este es uno de los motivos por el cual no funciona tu operador ternario la otra es la cual ya mencionarios en los comentarios que no podes iterar por un objeto key value con el map.

Si queres saber el length de un objeto key value necesitas usar:

```javascript
Object.keys(tareasProyecto).length
//devuelve 2
```

Esto cuenta cuantos keys tiene el objeto

```javascript
const tareaTest ={nombre: 'test'}
Object.keys(tareaTest).length
//devuelve 1
```

Para darte un ejemplo modifique tu declaracion:

`const tareasProyecto = { nombre: "Elegir Plataforma", estado: true };`

Y lo deje como un Array de Objetos:

```javascript
const tareasProyecto = [{nombre: "prueba", estado: true},{nombre: "prueba uno", estado: true}, {nombre: "prueba dos", estado: true}]
```

Ejecuta el código y velo en acción.

```js
// Example class component
class ListadoTareas extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log("rendered");
    const tareasProyecto = [{nombre: "prueba", estado: true},{nombre: "prueba uno", estado: true}, {nombre: "prueba dos", estado: true}]
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Proyecto: </h2>
            <ul className="listado-tareas">
                {tareasProyecto.length === 0 ? (
                    <li className="tarea">
                        <p>No hay Tareas</p>
                    </li>
                ) : tareasProyecto.map(tarea => <div>{tarea.nombre}</div>)
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ListadoTareas />,
  document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Espero que te sirva de ejemplo.
Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

En vez de

```
const tareasProyecto = { nombre: "Elegir Plataforma", estado: true };
```

Coloca

```
const tareasProyecto = [{ nombre: "Elegir Plataforma", estado: true }];
```

Recuerda la funcion map itera sobre un array de elementos.